# Images not being generated at correct size

Tags: uploads, attachments, media, options

I have my WordPress Media settings set [like so](http://cl.ly/JGIe/o). Based on these settings no generated large image should exceed the width of 540px.

I embed an image in a post [like so](http://cl.ly/JFvr/o). I choose "Large" as a image size, which should have a restricted width of 540px.

The end result is an [image](http://www.rustyrambles.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/p1000775-1024x768.jpg) of 1024x769px. Why won't the image adhere to my Media settings?

Comment: Your thumbnail is being created at http://www.rustyrambles.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/p1000775-150x112.jpg but I'm guessing you're saying you wish to use the large sized image, but it's not being genereated (i.e. http://www.rustyrambles.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/p1000775-540x405.jpg doesn't exist). Did you make the media settings change after uploading the image, or before?

Comment: Yes I'd like the "Large" size thumbnail, which I set to 540px max width. I made these settings changes before embedding the image, although not before uploading it. Surely this thumbnails generation step happens upon embed (at whatever size)?

Comment: Image sizes are generated on upload I believe. See answer below.

Comment: No, images are definitely generated and resized on upload, not on embed. Re-upload the image, or use a "regenerate thumbnails" plugin to resize existing images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try uploading the image again now you've set up the media settings, this should fix it.